# Two of my functions don't work correctly, IDE doesn't show errors or crashes

Tags: python, python-3.x

The deposit function and the withdraw function doesn't work. After populating the accounts, I can select D or W  menu options and input any number without causing the program to crash or causing an error. The program seems it is working correctly but when you check the balances using the S option, they are not updated.

```
Names=[]
accountnumbers=[]
balance=[]


def populatelist():
 position=0
 while(position<=2):
   yourname= str(input("Please enter a name: "))
   Names.append(yourname)
   account = int(  input("Please enter an account number: " ))
   accountnumbers.append(account)
   totalbalance = int(  input("Please enter a balance: "))
   balance.append(totalbalance)
   position = position + 1




##################################### DEPOSIT FUCNTION 
def deposit(accountnumber):
   foundposition=-1
   position=0
   if (len(accountnumbers)>0):
      while (position <=2):
         if (accountnumber==accountnumbers[position]):
            return position
         position = position + 1
   return foundposition




####################################  WITHDRAW FUNCTION
def withdraw(accountnumber):
   foundposition=-1
   position=0
   if (len(accountnumbers)>0):
      while (position <=2):
         if (accountnumber==accountnumbers[position]):
            return position
         position = position + 1
   return foundposition



def findingaccount(accountnumber):
   foundposition=-1
   position=0
   if (len(accountnumbers)>0):
      while (position <=2):
         if (accountnumber==accountnumbers[position]):
            return position
         position = position + 1
   return foundposition



def menuoptions():
   print ("**** MENU OPTIONS ****")
   print ("Type P to populate accounts")
   print ( "Type S to search for account")
   print ("Type E to exit")
   print ("Type D to deposit Amount")
   print ("Type W to withdraw Amount")
   choice = str(input("Please enter your choice: "))
   return choice



response=""
while response!= "E":
 response = menuoptions()
 if response=="P":
   populatelist()



 ########################### Deposit OPTION
 elif response=="D":
  searchaccount = int(input("Please enter the account number to add deposit: "))
  foundtheposition = deposit(searchaccount)
  money = int(input("Please enter the amount to be deposited: "))
  money + (balance[foundtheposition])



 ###########################  WITHDRAW OPTION
 elif  response=="W":
  searchaccount = int(input("Please enter the account number to withdraw: "))
  thenumber = withdraw(searchaccount)
  withdraw = int(input("how much for withdraw"))
  withdraw - (balance[thenumber])
  if (balance[thenumber]) < withdraw :
   print("ERROR: Not enough balance")




 elif response=="S":
  searchaccount = int(input("Please enter the account number to search: "))
  foundaposition = findingaccount(searchaccount)
  if ( foundaposition == -1 ):
   print ("The account number not found!")
  else:
   print ("Name is:" + str( Names[foundaposition])) 
   print (str(Names[foundaposition]) + " " + "account has the balance of :" +str(balance[foundaposition]))


 elif response=="E":
  print ("Thank you for using the program.")
  print ("Bye")
  exit

 else:
  print ("Invalid choice. Please try again!")
```

Comment: You should probably start with a Python tutorial. What do you expect this line to do, for example: `withdraw - (balance[thenumber])` ?

Answer (score 1):

You have logic error.

Just change

`money + (balance[foundtheposition])`

to

`balance[foundtheposition] = balance[foundtheposition] + money`

or using short-hand operator like

`balance[foundtheposition] += money`

Same for

`withdraw - (balance[thenumber])`

Cheers ...

Answer (score 0):

Your deposit scenario needs to add the amount into the selected account:

```
balance[thenumber] += money
```

*Fair warning* there are other errors in your program besides the accounts not updating.